# Simplifying Retrofit2 and Rxjava2 chained calls to use a Single instead of Observable in the final result

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, rx-java2

What I want to accomplish is to update my calls to where at the end of it all, when I subscribe, to return a Single and not an Observable because I only ever receive 1 result back but due to the nature of combining calls, I had to move to an observable to take advantage of the Observable methods to join results back into a single result.

The issue I was having was trying to figure out how to use the results from 1 call into another and then combine that result with another one and then return a combination of both.

The sequence of my calls is as follows:

1. Upload a list of logos

   - Receive the result of the logos upload which is more detailed data of the logos I just uploaded.
2. Use the list of results I just got and use that in a new request I make to create the book.

   - Receive the newly create book response which is just the book but with more auto generated data
3. Get the current author/user info ( I am forced to make this an Observable because a Single doesn't work with the .zip operator )
4. Use the author result and book details to create a POJO object. Return that as the final result. Currently, that is returned as an observable but there really will only ever be 1 entry returned so it makes little sense to return an observable. I am not sure how I can transform this to return a Single so I would appreciate any suggestions.

This is the code I have right now. The objects and such are just for example but the sequence and calls are exactly what I have:

**Retrofit service:**

```
@GET("/api/Profile/Author")
Observable<AuthorJson> getAuthor();

@POST("/api/Logo")
Observable<BookLogoJson> uploadBookLogos(@Header("Content-Type") String content_type, @Body RequestBody logo);

@POST("/api/Book")
Single<BookDetailsJson> newBook(@Body BookDetailRequest request);
```

**The actual implementation**

```
List<Book> bookLogos = ...;

Observable.fromIterable(bookLogos)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .flatMap(new Function<String, ObservableSource<BookLogoJson>>() {
                    @Override
                    public ObservableSource<BookLogoJson> apply(@NonNull String bookLogos) throws Exception {
                        return mApi.uploadBookLogos(mContentType, getRequestBody(bookLogos, context));
                    }
                }).toList().flatMap(new Function<List<BookLogoJson>, SingleSource<BookDetailsJson>>() {
                    @Override
                    public SingleSource<BookDetailsJson> apply(@NonNull List<BookLogoJson> bookLogosRaw) throws Exception {
                        BookDetailRequest request = new BookDetailRequest();
                        for(BookLogoJson logo : bookLogosRaw){
                            request.mLogos.add(logo.mId);
                        }
                        return mApi.newBook(request);
                    }
                }).toObservable().flatMap(new Function<BookDetailsJson, ObservableSource<Book>>() {
                    @Override
                    public ObservableSource<Book> apply(@NonNull BookDetailsJson BookDetailsJson) throws Exception {
                        return Observable.zip(mApi.getAuthor(),
                                Observable.just(BookDetailsJson),
                                new BiFunction<AuthorJson, BookDetailsJson, Book>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public Book apply(AuthorJson author, BookDetailsJson bookDetails) throws Exception {
                                        return mConverter.getBook(author, bookDetails);
                                    }
                                });
                    }
                })
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeWith(new Observer<Book>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSubscribe(@NonNull Disposable d) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(@NonNull Book book) {
                        // Here, I will only ever get 1 Book so an observable makes no sense.
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(@NonNull Throwable e) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete() {
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

It is actually quite simple, since the result from `toList().flatMap(...)` is already a `Single`.

Simply remove the call to `toObservable()` and modify the `flatMap` afterwards to return a `Single`:

```
mApi.getAuthor().firstOrError().map(new Function<AuthorJson, Book>() {
                        public Book apply(@NonNull AuthorJson author) throws Exception {
        // bookDetails captured by anonymous function
        return mConverter.getBook(author, bookDetails);
    }
});
```

In addition, Retrofit's RxJava converter also accepts `Single` as a replacement for `Observable`. That might apply here since the requests always produce a single result or an error. (`Completable` can be used for no-response requests)

Comment: a Single is what I actually want to use but can't because of .zip. It's possible my question did not make that clear, but that is what I am trying to achieve all my calls will never return more than 1 result, hence Single will be more appropriate.

Comment: Why is a `.zip` required? Looking at your code you only need to merge a `Single` and an already calculated object, which can be done with a simple `.map`.

Comment: I have actually another call that I need to make before returning the Book.  How would you modify your code to actually make another request after returning the final book? That's kind of my problem - I need to make a first request(1), use that request result to create another request(2), and then combine that result from (2) with one last request(3) that will return a Single object which uses data from (2) and (3). I hope that explains the situation a little better. The move from (2) to (3) is the reason I am using a .zip